# Question about Sharepoint App Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app-permissions, sharepoint-store

I hope you guys could help me out. I have an average understanding in Sharepoint as well as Administering it. Currently we have Sharepoint Online Plan 1. Now I will describe my situation below.

A user has a site collection and I created a Sharepoint group for that user. Pretty much she has the power to do anything inside her site. Also I made myself Site Collection Admin for the site and not her since I want to have some sense of security. Anyways, she requested to enable the ability to add App from Sharepoint Store. And so I set up my first App Catalog and also configured the App Purchases and Apps for Office from the Store to "Yes". After I deployed it she can now add apps with no issues.

However, there is only one app that is showing "Sorry, only site collection administrators can add or give access to this app." ?? Which confuses me... are there some apps that won't let the user add an app or restricts the user from downloading/installing apps even though I have given them full permission to do so? Is this a permission issue? I know I could add it myself since I'm Site Collection Admin. I'm pretty much stumped as I search the net.. Hope one of you guys could help or explain why is that so? Thanks so much! -Matt

Comment: What permissions is the app requesting? The user adding it must have the permissions it is requesting.  I think the app-only context requires site collection admin.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I was thinking along those line too. When I looked deeper into the app (BeyondKey Metro Tiles) it didn't state anything nor in their Dev website. But since you mention about the App-Only context requires site collection admin... I now know that this exist. Would you please care to direct me where to find this info? Perhaps inside Sharepoint Admin app store? Maybe I'm overlooking things in the store.

Comment: I was wrong about the app-only bit.  I don't know why I thought that, especially since I'm in the same scenario as you.  I think it's a bug/update/issue with SharePoint Online, since I've started seeing that message in my own tenant when I was developing an app.  The app I created uses app-only, but I still see the message when I remove that permission, which leads me to think it's a bug/update/issue.  I tried to talk to Microsoft about it, but they told me that I was on my own, since it was a custom app.  Perhaps you may have better luck, as you're dealing with the store.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks for the effort to clear things up. I did some research on your key word of App-Only which opened up a path about App-Only Policies and other permissions as well as App Manifest which requires Visual Studio (which I don't know how to use lol) You are right, it could be a bug as you had said. The only way I can think of a workaround is if I could add the user as a temporary Site Collection Admin so she could install it... or I could add the app myself for her. But thanks for clarifying. If someone else have any input for this, please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm the Site Collection Admin, I decided to add the app for the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the app requires tenant level permissions.  I don't know when or why this change was made.  This requires you to install the app for your users (or approve the installation, if they submit a request).  [This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35633.troubleshooting-app-debug-and-installation-issue-in-sharepoint-online.aspx) article shows how developers can work around this while debugging.